# Let $R$ be the binary relation on $\mathbb{N}$ defined by $xRy$ ($x$ is in relation to $y$) defined by: $xRy$ if $xy=49$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $R$ be the binary relation on $\mathbb{N}$ defined by $xRy$ ($x$ is in relation to $y$) defined by: $xRy$ if $xy=49$

A) $R$ is reflexive and $R$ is symmetric

B) $R$ is reflexive and $R$ is not symmetric

C) $R$ is not reflexive and $R$ is symmetric

D) $R$ is not reflexive and $R$ is not symmetric

The answer is C. I understand why it is symmetric, but why it is not reflexive? For example, if I have $xy=7\times7=49$ (which is reflexive relation, isn't it?). Anyone explain please?

Thank You

Comment: What is the definition of a reflexive relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a relation $R$ to be *reflexive* means that $xRx$ for **ALL** $x$ in the domain of the relation. Yes, it's true that in this example $x=7$ satisfies $xRx$ because $7\cdot7=49$. But is it true that $xRx$ for **ALL** $x\in\mathbb{N}$? I.e., is it true that for all natural numbers $x^2=49$?

Comment: I got it. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 2):

Reflexive is: $\forall x$, $xRx$.

Find an $x$ such that $x^2 \ne 49$